# Problems with pattern color

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, pattern

Why in the following MWE in all shapes the pattern color is as in the first one regardless that it is defined differently?

```
%%%% pattern-color
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,patterns,backgrounds}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
        hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
        hatch distance=5pt,
        hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
        hatch thickness=5pt
        }
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{north east hatch}% name
    {\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}% below left
    {\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}% above right
    {\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
    {
        \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    start chain = going below,
  node distance = 2mm,
    Node/.style = {minimum width=#1,
                   shape=rectangle,
                   draw, fill=white,
                   on chain},
 Pattern/.style = {pattern=north east hatch,
                    pattern color=#1,%teal!30,
                    hatch distance=7pt,
                    hatch thickness=3pt},
    font=\small\sffamily]
%----------------
\node[Node=44mm,Pattern=red!30]     {desired pattern color: red};
\node[Node=44mm,Pattern=cyan!30,
      preaction={fill=yellow}]      {desired pattern color: cyan};
\node[Node=44mm]                    {without pattern};
\node[Node=44mm,Pattern=orange!30,
      preaction={fill=gray!30}]     {desired pattern color: orange};
%---
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in `\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex`. The internal macro `\pgf@declarepatternmutable` saves the pattern type as `7` instead of `#7`. The corrected line should read:

```
\expandafter\gdef\csname pgf@pattern@type@#1\endcsname{#7}%
```

With this change the patterns work as expected.

Comment: Will be this bug fixed in the next CVS of TikZ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a diagnostic, though not a solution.

The code for a form only pattern should ***not*** include colour code at all. So setting the colour within the definition is surely a no-no, if the documentation is to be believed.

However, that just turns everything black or white...

OK. Start with the code from page 1064 of the manual for the `stars` pattern. This works fine, as advertised:

[image: blacks and reds]

Now add your variables to it so that we have:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tikzset{
  hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
  hatch distance=5pt,
  hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
  hatch thickness=5pt
}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{stars}
{\pgfpointorigin}
{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}
{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}
{
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{.5cm}{.5cm}}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointpolar{0}{4mm}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{144}{4mm}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{288}{4mm}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{72}{4mm}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{216}{4mm}}
  \pgfpathclose%
  \pgfusepath{fill}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw[pattern=stars] (0,0) rectangle (1.5,2);
    \filldraw[pattern=stars,pattern color=red](1.5,0) rectangle (3,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

All is less fine:

[image: all blacks]

So it does not work as advertised...

There's another question about code in this part of the manual not working. I'll see if I can find it (I asked it). Not the same issue, but maybe it will provide a clue.

## EDIT

It is not that it is impossible to change the colour...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns,chains}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{north east hatch}% name
{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}% below left
{\pgfqpoint{7pt}{3pt}}% above right
{\pgfpoint{6pt}{6pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{3pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{7pt}{3pt}}
  \pgfpathclose
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}


\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    start chain = going below,
    node distance = 2mm,
    Node/.style =
    {
      minimum width=#1,
      shape=rectangle,
      draw, fill=white,
      on chain
    },
    Pattern/.style =
    {
      pattern=north east hatch,
      pattern color=#1
    },
    font=\small\sffamily
    ]
    \node[Node=44mm, Pattern=red!30]     {desired pattern color: red};
    \node[Node=44mm, Pattern=cyan!30]      {desired pattern color: cyan};
    \node[Node=44mm]                    {without pattern};
    \node[Node=44mm, Pattern=orange!30]     {desired pattern color: orange};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: colourful patterns]

Comment: OK. I had [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232034/declaring-patterns-with-variables-in-tikz-understanding-the-effect-of-the-varia?rq=1) in mind but I don't think it is helpful.

Comment: Huh, here seems to be more problems than I imagine... The description of patterns in TikZ manual is to short to be useful. As I now understand, the pattern color is global defined and can not be change after it selection. I look in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40854/pattern-color-differs-from-normal-color, but I didn't succeed to adopt it to my need, because I don't understand it.

Comment: @Zarko What do you mean? You certainly can use `pattern color` to change the colour multiple times. See edit above. (I know I've made a mess of the pattern - it is just to show the colour changes.)

Comment: Sorry. I don't see what that link has which is relevant here. It seems entirely unrelated to me.