# Tikz: shaded ellipses with overlap merging color

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

How is it possible to draw two ellipses in TikZ, say one gray with centers at (1,1)and (2,2) and one orange with centers at (0,2) and (1,3) such that they have a small overlap over which the colour merges?

I do manage to draw circles at the moment but at the ovelap one goes on top of the other.

Comment: Show us, what you try so far. Using `tikz` code for ellipse is for example `\draw (1,1) ellipse [x radius=1cm,y radius=.5cm];`

Comment: If you want the color to merge, you either need to use `opacity` or to fill the overlap (for example using `clip`) with a new colour that you previously defined.

Answer (score 2):

The standard method, that is, auto color mixing is using `[blend group=screen]` inside a `[transparency group]`, see [pfgmanual.pdf](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en) Section 23.3 Blend Modes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[transparency group]
\begin{scope}[blend mode=screen]
\fill[blue] (1,1) ellipse (2 and 1);
\fill[red]  (2,2) ellipse (2 and 1);
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

An equivalent and shorter code using the shorthand `[blend group=screen]`

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[blend group=screen]
\fill[cyan] (1,1) ellipse (2 and 1);
\fill[magenta]  (2,2) ellipse (2 and 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Edit(by @hpekristiansen) just to show the `rgb` options influence on the additive mixing colors compared to the `blend mode=screen` mixing of primary colors:

With `rgb` option:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm,rgb]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[blend group=screen]
\fill[red] ( 90:.6) circle (1);
\fill[green] (210:.6) circle (1);
\fill[blue] (330:.6) circle (1);
\fill[yellow] (2,0) circle(.2); \fill[magenta] (2,.5) circle(.2); \fill[cyan] (2,1) circle(.2); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: RGB mixing]

Without `rgb` option:

[image: Mixing without rgb option]

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of this. Just for extra info: the manual says that the `transparency group` can be omitted, but it can cause render problems. I have no problem in mac preview.

Comment: @hpekristiansen In fact, the answer is not complete. The color of the intersection region should be `red + blue = violet`, but it is not ???? Do you mind checking together with me? https://sciencetrends.com/what-color-does-red-and-blue-make/ `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[blend group=screen]
\fill[blue] (1,1) ellipse (2 and 1);
\fill[red]  (2,2) ellipse (2 and 1);
\fill[purple] (5,0) circle(.2);
\fill[violet] (5,.5) circle(.2);
\fill[magenta] (5,1) circle(.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: I do not get violet, but should you not expect magenta? - I do not get that either. Edit: I do not get any of the three colors. I will investigate the different blend modes, and what color to expect.

Comment: I am just curious about what the color of the intersection is!

Comment: I am lost when it comes to things like this. I am on a mac and I have NOT "True Tone"  or "Night Shift" on. I would thin that the primary colors on screen are correct: Here is what I get when measure with "Digital Color Meter" directly from screen": `Red: 255,0,0`.`Green:0,255,55`.`Blue:0,5,251`.`Red+Green:255,255,55`.`Red+Blue:255,5,251`.`Green+Blue:0,255,252`.`Cyan:0,163,217`.`Magenta:217,18,123`.`Yellow:255,241,55`

Comment: The mixing is a better magenta than `magenta`. `magenta` is way too dark. Red+Blue actually gives magenta (but is for some reason shown slightly of on my screen).

Comment: `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[blend group=screen]
\fill[red] ( 90:.6) circle (1);
\fill[green] (210:.6) circle (1);
\fill[blue] (330:.6) circle (1);
\fill[yellow] (2,0) circle(.2); \fill[magenta] (2,.5) circle(.2); \fill[cyan] (2,1) circle(.2); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40888/8650 `magenta` is not magenta and neither is `blue!50!red`

Comment: This works: `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm,rgb]{standalone}`

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[cyan] (1,1) ellipse (2 and 1);
        \fill[orange,opacity=.8] (2,2) ellipse (2 and 1);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[cyan] (1,1) ellipse (2 and 1);
        \fill[orange] (2,2) ellipse (2 and 1);
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (1,1) ellipse (2 and 1);
            \fill[orange!80!cyan] (2,2) ellipse (2 and 1);      
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: V1]
[image: V2]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want the colour be shaded, stronger in the centers and fade out so as to simulate two normal distributions overlapping.

Comment: @Marion: This is a completely new question. You need to search for an answer, and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red, rotate around={45:(1.5,1.5)}, opacity=0.5] (1.5,1.5) ellipse [x radius=sqrt(1.5), y radius=1];
\fill (1,1) circle[radius=0.1] (2,2) circle[radius=0.1];
\fill[green, rotate around={45:(0.5,2.5)}, opacity=0.5] (0.5,2.5) ellipse [x radius=sqrt(1.5), y radius=1];
\fill (0,2) circle[radius=0.1] (1,3) circle[radius=0.1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two overlapping ellipses]